# neo4j conditional relationship

Tags: java, graph, neo4j

I am currently working on a program using graph db - neo4j and I need to realize the following function.

[image]

1. I have two types of nodes, type **A** means stage, type **N** means let the user do some selections.
2. First we have node **A1**, which has several (2-5) type **N** children, **N1**, **N2**, **N3**, ...
3. Nodes **A1** also have child nodes **A2**, **A3**, ...
4. In java, after arriving at **A1**, I will ask the users to do some selections according to **Ni**, then go to a type **A** child based on a function of the selections. For example, if **N1**=true, **N2**=true, **N3**=false, I go to **A2**, otherwise, I goto **A3**.

BTW, I will meet this situation many many times in my program. Do you guys have any idea how to implement it efficiently.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `N2` lacks in your diagram; is that the second N node from the top or something else?

Comment: @fge It's a typo, should be **N2**.

Comment: Does that mean that only one node can be returned? What if no nodes, or more than 1, are common children of the selected N nodes?

Comment: @fge Yes, only one node will be returned. I do not quite understand your question. Actually, the topology does not have to be my figure. Basically, what I want is to have users input some values at **A**, and then go to one of the children **Mi** bases on the input values.

Comment: OK, I don't know neo4j that much, but if you use a `Set` to collect the children of the first N, you can then .removeAll() children from the second N, etc and what is left in the set should be your node. Maybe neo4j can do this more efficiently, though.

Comment: How about connecting the Nx with appropriate true/false relationships with the Ax nodes? Then if the user made the decisions you follow the relationships they have outlined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestion for Setup

```
(Ax)-[:TRUE ]->(Nx)-[:TRUE ]->(Ax+1)
(Ax)-[:FALSE]->(Nx)-[:FALSE]->(Ax+1)
```

Suggestion for Query

```
 MATCH (a:A {id:1}),
       (a)-[:TRUE]-> (n)-[:FALSE]->(a2),
       (a)-[:FALSE]->(n2)-[:TRUE]->(a2),
       (a)-[:TRUE]-> (n)-[:FALSE]->(a2)
 RETURN a2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Michael Hunger, I think I find an acceptable solution, although it seems a lot of work to do.

Specifically, I expand all the pathes from **A1** through **Ni** and link the only path when all **Ni**=true to **A2*** and all the other paths to **A3** as the following graph:

[image]