# Modeling relationship conditions in Neo4j

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm exploring Neo4j and would like to implement something to the effect of:

```
(n1)-[r:next if n1.value > 2]->(n2)
(n1)-[r:next if n1.value <= 2]->(n3)
```

Such that if I query (q)-[r]->(t) I do:

```
match (n:n1) set n.value=1
match (q)-[r]->[t] return q,r,t
```

I get:

```
(n1)-[next]->(n3)
```

and if I do

```
match (n:n1) set n.value=3
match (q)-[r]->[t] return q,r,t
```

I get:

```
(n1)-[next]->(n2)
```

I've seen something to the effect of this here:
[Modeling conditional relationships in neo4j v.2 (cypher)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22309138/modeling-conditional-relationships-in-neo4j-v-2-cypher) and here: [neo4j conditional relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694532/neo4j-conditional-relationship)

However, this doesn't suit my needs for two reasons:

1. No automatic resolution. For example, I am supposing that I can query this using `match (n1)-[r]->(n3) where n1.value = r.value`. I haven't tried it yet.
2. Using numeric values/ranges. Per the example above, I'd like to be able to use this for ranges.

Alternatively, I just might be missing something completely...

Comment: I don't follow. What's wrong with `MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE r.value = 1 RETURN n, r, m`? Or `MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE 1 < r.value < 3 RETURN n, r, m`?

Comment: I think I envisioned that n.value could change. If so, correct me if I'm wrong here but if n1.value = 3, then `MATCH (n)-[r]->(m) WHERE 1 < r.value < 3 RETURN n, r, m` would still return relationships to (n2) and (n3) right? I also just noticed a typo in my question - Sorry if that caused confusion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (you have a few errors in your question), this might work for you:

```
MATCH (n1 {id:123}), (n2 {id: 234}), (n3 {id: 345})
WITH n1, n2,
  CASE WHEN n1.value > 2 THEN {a:[1]} WHEN n1.value <= 2 THEN {b:[1]} END AS todo
FOREACH(x IN todo.a | CREATE (n1)-[:NEXT]->(n2))
FOREACH(y IN todo.b | CREATE (n1)-[:NEXT]->(n3));
```

The `MATCH` clause finds the 3 nodes.

The `WITH` clause creates exactly one of the following:

- a `todo.a` collection if `n.value > 2`
- a `todo.b` collection if `n.value <= 2`
- a `NULL` `todo`.

If either `todo.a` or `todo.b` exist, then one (and only one) of the `FOREACH` clauses will create the appropriate relationship.

Comment: Thanks for this, I *think* I understand what's going on. If you don't mind, would you mind telling me where the errors are, or fixing them (just want to make sure the question is correctly formed).

Comment: Your question first states that you want a relationship to `n2` if `n1.value > 2`. However, you go on and illustrate a relationship to `n2` if `value` is 1. Similar errors exist with `n3`.

Comment: RE: the typo you point out - I switched up n2 and n3 in my outcomes examples - I edited the question. Based on your answer (and the comment by Nicole White), there is no way to do this? In your answer, if I set `n1.value` to be 3 initially, I would create the corresponding relationship (`[:NEXT]->(n2)`), however, when I modify `n1.value` to be 1, this relationship does not change, while also creating the relationship `[:NEXT]->(n3)`. Right?

Comment: In my answer, if you set `n1.value` to `3` initially, the first `FOREACH` will create a `NEXT` relationship to `n2`, NOT `n3`. Every time you run my answer, a new relationship can be created, but nothing is deleted. (Of course, if you want different behavior, you can change the query or use a different one.)

Comment: Got it, yes that's my thought exactly. Based on my understanding of your response, I think maybe neo4j isnt the best tool for the job for this instance... Thanks again.

Comment: If you wanted a different result, you can probably alter the query. What is it that you want to do that you think neo4j cannot handle?

Comment: I plan on using neo4j to model a survey and responses to survey and skip patterns (since a survey is simply a DAG). So, if q1 is "What is your age" and q2 is "If under 25, when did you graduate college" and q3 is "If over 25, what is your most recent degree", I want to be able to find potential paths a survey taker might take through the survey, depending on their answers. In this case, if the survey taker is 26 years old, they will skip straight to q3. If so here, there are two valid paths in the survey: q1->q2, and q1->q3. Thoughts on modeling this would be great!